# Angular4 Typescript Interface dynamic type conversion issue for number from server

Tags: angular, http, typescript, interface

I have a model of

```
export class School {
    school_id: number;
    school_name: string;
    school_code: string;
}
```

Once I subscribe with

My variable Initialisation for school data

```
schools: School[] = [];
```

My data Service

```
getSchool(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiEndPoint}/api/getSchool`,this.jwt())
    .map((response:Response) => response.json() );
  }  

getSchoolData() {
    this.dataService.getSchool().subscribe(response => {
        this.schools = response.data;
        console.log(this.schools);
    });
  }
```

The console log object gives

```
[0:Object
school_code:"ALL"
school_id:"1"
school_name:"ALL"
]
```

I expected school_id to number and its setting string. How can I restrict so that school_id will be number instead as of interface.

Comment: The data is being sent from your server. If the server sets that value as string then it will come as a string.

Comment: Actually in MySql the field is type of int. I am doing a json encode while sending. But why its not failing and setting it a string.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it at backend level by json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) in PHP response. But still why Angular is not throwing error when a numeric is set by string.

Comment: Your types don't exist at runtime. Typescript does not do any runtime type validation.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I fixed it at backend level by

```
json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)
```

in PHP response.